# Is there a way to zerofill the page file once for VM compaction?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, ntfs, wipe

I know it's not good practice to completely disable the page file even with seemingly sufficient amounts of RAM. I have a number of Windows VMs that naturally have a page file enabled at the default size (which appears to be based on the RAM size).

I also know there is a way to set a policy to wipe (i.e. zero-fill from what I read) the page file on shutdown in Windows.

Is there also a way to have this happen for a single shutdown only?

---

My intent is to zerofill the page file for better compaction of the guest disk. However, I do not want to mount the disk from my host as the NTFS version differs for several of the VMs. So everything that happens should happen *inside* the VM.

After `sdelete -z X:` I want to be able to have Windows itself wipe the page file *once* and next time it is booted it should *not* be the default policy to wipe the page file.

Comment: Aside from the explanation why you want to do this, this might just aswell be the same question ignoring any references to VMs.  E.g. How do I zero fill the pagefile on windows/barehardware but only do that once.

Comment: @Hennes: same question as which one? In principle a bootable ISO would work, that would require a more opinion-based question and answers (which I asked on Software Recommendations).

Comment: Am I missing something? Surely you set the policy, reboot, then clear it again.

Comment: @AFH: yes you are missing something big. If I boot it again to disable the policy, the page file is "dirty" again. Hence, no need to enable the policy the first time around, because rebooting into the system will undo the effect. Wiping the page file only ever makes sense if the system is left offline afterward (for compaction/archiving in my case).

Comment: Yes, I didn't infer that. I thought that you wanted to zero the file so that if little swapping occurred, the file would remain mostly zeroes and so still compress well.

Comment: @AFH: fair enough. And I'll take a no as an answer to my question. But if possible I'll go for the single-shot solution instead of having to boot again and disable the policy manual. But thanks for the input. It *is* appreciated.